# After update to Ubuntu Jelly 22.04 monitor resolution changed. Gamma not recognised. Nvida drivers are not loaded

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, monitor, nvidia-settings

I will describe you the problem I am trying to solve. I have a desktop computer with a nvidia card (G92 [GeForce 8800 GTS 512]) which was running a previous version of Ubuntu and still runs jelly 22.04.

In previous version of Ubuntu happened the following:
With a fresh installation of ubuntu, my screen was freezing occasionally. I have found that the problem was the graphics card drivers, so I installed Nvidia drivers and in the Settings I enabled proprietary Graphics drivers to Nvidia. This setting worked fine. No freezing anymore and screen's resolution was optimal.

Lately I did an upgrade to Jelly-Fish Ubuntu 22.04. The screen resolution changed to 1024 x 768 (4:3) which disturbs me. I tried several workarounds to correct it but nothing worked. So I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu Jelly-Fish 22.04 and I returned to the correct monitor settings which are the following

Samsung Electric Company 24"
My setting is 1920 x 1200 (16:10) at 59,95 Hz

But the system kept freezing so I advanced to Nvidia drivers installation to enable proprietary drivers but this didn't work. Resolution changed again to 1024 x 768 (4:3) and I don't manage to correct resolution.
xrandr gives me the following output

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm

From settings tab named "about" I see the installed graphics is llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits).

I don't have deep knowledge on how to fix this. I would like firstly to correct the gamma problem, and then correct the resolution. If the system freezes again, I would like to enable Nvidia drivers as proprietary (a recipe that was working fine before the update).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you don't need to be told how old your graphics card is...

As always, the problem with legacy hardware is the support being dropped anytime and without notice. That's what happened here. The latest (and only) Nvidia driver supporting your card is 340.xx and that branch is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories.

You may want to add the [graphics drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and then open Additional Drivers and select the "340" drivers that should then be available.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```